# Round-off if decimal value is .6 or higher

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this requirement that every decimal values will be round-off, so I used the built-in function ROUND in SQL.

But I have this requirement where below or equal to .5 of decimal values will not be round-off. I have researched on this but can't find any results related to my concern.

Below should be the expected result

```
SELECT ROUND(200.521231,0) --- 200.000000  
SELECT ROUND(200.436231,0) --- 200.000000  
SELECT ROUND(-200.436231,0) --- -200.000000  
SELECT ROUND(200.621231,0) --- 201.000000
```

I'm using MS-SQL Server

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Both returns `201` for me

Comment: Yes, That is my problem, if the decimal value has .5 or higher should retain the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trivial thing to do is:

```
SELECT ROUND(@x -0.1,0)
```

where @x is the decimal value you're rounding

if @x is allowed to be negative:

```
SELECT IF( @x>0, ROUND(@x -0.1,0), ROUND(@x +0.1,0))
```

Comment: What about negative values?